Creating a Rmarkdown table with multiple cohorts
I am trying to create a table that has 5 cohorts of interest (plus the overall). As in the image the Group 3-5 are subgroups of Group 1 and I only want the overall column to be out of Group 1 and Group 2. I am trying to do this i rMarkdown using the kable function. Any guidance would be appreciated. Currently I am only able to get two groups and the overall column to show
Structure of table
I am trying to do this i rMarkdown using the kable function. Any guidance would be appreciated. Currently I am only able to get two groups and the overall column to show. I think the issue is that in my code I am assigning a stratification variable that is binary.
My code looks like this:
mytable<- calc_summ_stats(data= dataset, dd= dataset, column= "name", missing_in_denominator=F, strata_var="startification variable", stats_"stats_var", precision =1, statistical_testing = Null) 

I am also using the Kable function to produce the table.
